# geom_boxplot() looking weird in R Shiny but working well in .rmd in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, boxplot, r-plotly

Here's the code I have for a boxplot, I have chosen the variable "Income Level" in the y-axis.

```
data %>%
filter(!is.na(incomelevel)) %>% 

  mutate(incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "highincome", "High", incomelevel), 
         incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "lowermiddleincome", "Lower-Middle", incomelevel), 
         incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "uppermiddleincome", "Upper-Middle", incomelevel), 
         incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "lowincome", "Low", incomelevel)) %>%
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = life_satisfaction, y = incomelevel)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
    labs(x = "", y = "Life Satisfaction")
```

The boxplot looks as desired!

[image]

Now when I try to integrate it in shiny, the boxplot looks very weird:
I first slightly manipulated the Data:

```
        data_boxplots <- data %>%
filter(!is.na(incomelevel)) %>% 
mutate(incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "highincome", "High", incomelevel), 
       incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "lowermiddleincome", "Lower-Middle", incomelevel), 
       incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "uppermiddleincome", "Upper-Middle", incomelevel), 
       incomelevel = ifelse(incomelevel == "lowincome", "Low", incomelevel)) %>%
rename("Income Level" = incomelevel,
       "Freedom Status" = freedom_status,
       "Region" = region)
```

Then here's what I have in the **UI**:

```
      tabPanel("Boxplots", 
           
           mainPanel(                                      # mainPanel
             h1("Comparing Life Satisfaction with Various Other Factors"),           
             withSpinner(plotlyOutput("boxplot")),
             
             varSelectInput(inputId = "variable3", label = "Select Factor to Compare", data = data_project_boxplots[c(17, 22, 25)]
             )
             
           )),
```

And here's the code from the **Server**:

```
    output$boxplot <- renderPlotly({ 
       
  data_boxplots %>%
    
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = life_satisfaction, y = .data[[input$variable3]])) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = "Life Satisfaction")
  
})
```

But now I get an incredibly strange boxplot. I basically copy pasted this method for other plots and those plots seem to work totally okay.

[image]

Do let me know what went wrong, thanks so much! (Note that I have used Plotly for this)

Comment: I wonder whether `.data[[input$variable3]]` might be of type character, rather than numeric? Perhaps try `as.numeric(.data[[input$variable3]])`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was wondering if it's related to that. 
Unfortunately when I did `y =as.numeric(.data[[input$variable3]])` I'm getting the error `"missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"`. I also messed around with `parse_number` but I'm still not getting the desired results.

Comment: You have a `ggplot` object in a `renderPlotly`.  You need to use `renderPlot` or convert it to `ggplotly()` object.